# Angular services: singleton, non-singleton, lazy loaded and ngrx. How to provide them?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to get my head around the different ways of declaring services in Angular applications and when to use which, and also how to deal with store slices via ngrx.

In Angular 6, the recommended approach is to use providedIn: 'root' for singleton services: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services
This way they will be tree-shakeable and only 1 instance will be created when the app bootstraps.

What I don't understand is:

- Is there any use for non-singleton services at all? 
  I understand that you can add services to the list of providers of a component, and a new instance of the services will be created whenever the component is created, and destroyed when the component is destroyed. The advantage I see is the memory release, but on the other hand the Angular team doesn't mention this at all and it recommends to provide the services in the root module.
- Is there any case in which providing the service in a feature module makes more sense that in the root injector? 
  As I understand it, if instead of 'root' you select another module, the service will be created when this module is loaded. This seems to make sense for lazy-loaded modules, to avoid having to load services you don't need on bootstrap. If I try to do this with a module that is using ngrx, I get a warning for a circular dependency, as the Admin effects need to import the Admin service, and the Admin service is defined as providedIn: 'AdmimModule'. What am I doing wrong?
  I also get a circular dependency as it follows:
  AdminRoutingModule -> AdminComponent -> AdminService -> AdminModule -> AdminRoutingModule

Also, is there any space for static methods? It seems to me that all methods of singleton service could be declared as static. I have read static methods are harder to test, is this the only reason not to use them?

Comment: Why are static methods hard to test? Just setup, call method, do test. What is harder about static methods that any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for providing a service at a component level is so that a unique instance of that service is available to all components in the hierarchy under the component that provides it. Just imagine if you have two components on your page that need to share data across the component hierarchy. If they were to use an application wide singleton service then the two components would interfere with each other. Providing the service at the component level means that they can use their own instance of the service without effecting any other component outside of the hierarchy.

Comment: OK I see, so if we are using ngrx to hold the app state there is no need really for component-level services, right? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at a library I am working on that gives the push based data flow benefits of a store but makes it incredible simple to setup and reason about without any of the ridiculous amount of boilerplate involved with ngrx.

https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-rxcache

It is based on RxJs Behaviour Subjects and gives you all the benefits of push based data flow and still allows you to use the dumb-smart component architecture.

I have redone the official ngrx demo application in it here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tsrf1f

If you compare it to the official ngrx demo app at

https://stackblitz.com/github/ngrx/platform/tree/61cbfe537f9df8cef3dd4a6ee0b8f483e49653f4

You will see how much simpler it is to setup and work with.